# Need Handlebars.js to render object data instead of "[Object object]"

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars templates and JSON data is already represented in [Object object], how do I parse this data outside of the Handlebars? For example, I'm trying to populate a JavaScript variable on the page through a handlebars tag, but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm using ExpressJS w/ Handlebars for templating.  In my route, I have this:

```
var user = {}
user = {'id' : 123, 'name' : 'First Name'}

res.render('index', {user : user});
```

Then in my index.hbs template, I now have a `{{user}}` object.  I can use `{{#each}}` to iterate through the object just fine.  However, I'm also using Backbonejs and I want to pass this data to a View, such as this:

```
myView = new myView({
   user : {{user}}
});
```

The problem is that `{{user}}` simply shows `[Object object]` in the source. If I put it in console.log I get an error that says 'Unexpected Identifier'.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on "doesn't work." Can you provide a [relevant snippet of code](http://sscce.org/) and a description of what you're expecting instead of `[Object object]`? If you're simply trying to see the object's keys/values, you'll want to use `console.log` with a debugger or [`JSON.stringify`](http://caniuse.com/json).

Comment: Console.log shows [Object object] also.  I'll update post to explain better.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

When outputting `{{user}}`, Handlebars will first retrieve the `user`'s `.toString()` value. For plain `Object`s, the [default result of this is the `"[object Object]"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Description) you're seeing.

To get something more useful, you'll either want to display a specific property of the object:

```
{{user.id}}
{{user.name}}
```

Or, you can use/define a helper to format the object differently:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});
```

```
myView = new myView({
    user : {{{json user}}} // note triple brackets to disable HTML encoding
});
```

Comment: it should be: {{{json user}}}, otherwise the json string will be encoded.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. For Express users:
`app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
var Handlebars = require('hbs');`

Comment: Works great. Also for [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) users: `var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({   
   helpers: {
    json: function (context) {
     return JSON.stringify(context);
    }
   }
  }));`

Comment: Or just include the helpers when you render. `res.render('index', { var1: 'some value', helpers: { json: function (context) { return JSON.stringify(context);  } });`

Comment: Worked like a charm! How neat.

Comment: What if user is created with new User(...) ? JSON.stringify() will lost all code from the User class/prototype, and leave you with a plain object. How to pass an Object as is ?

Comment: This can be required when you are passing that object (user in this case) to JavaScript...

Comment: @acmoune Going over the network, from server to client, the object has to be serialized into a data format. So sending it as it is in memory isn't strictly possible. Though, you may be able to share the definition of the `User` type and reconstruct the instance for the client – `user : new User({{{json user}}})`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, You are right, I would have prefer to be able to do `var data = JSON.parse({{user}})` or simply `var data = {{user}}`, but it is just impossible.

Answer (score 16):

You can simple *stringify* the JSON:

```
var user = {}
user = {'id' : 123, 'name' : 'First Name'};
// for print
user.stringify = JSON.stringify(user);
```

Then in template print by:

```
{{{user.stringify}}};
```

Comment: The answers above are splendid. I actually encountered an issue when rendering the JSON string in the view because i had an unescaped quote, This answer solved that https://stackoverflow.com/a/22105906/7998284

Answer (score 7):

I'm using server-side templating in node-js, but this may apply client-side as well.  I register [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski)'s json helper in node. In my handler, I add context (such as addressBook) via res.locals. Then I can store the context variable client-side as follows:

```
<script>
  {{#if addressBook}}
  console.log("addressBook:", {{{json addressBook}}});
  window.addressBook = {{{json addressBook}}};
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

Note the triple curlies (as pointed out by [Jim Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888639/jim-liu)).

Answer (score 5):

You can render the keys/values of a list or object in a Handlebars template like this:

```
{{#each the_object}}
  {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Note that this will print `[object Object]` for nested objects

Answer (score 4):

Just improving the answer from @sajjad.

Adding a 'pre' tag will make it look a lot nicer.

```
<pre>
  {{#each the_object}}
    {{@key}}: {{this}}
  {{/each}}
</pre>
```

Comment: This is actually a good answer if you don't want to register a helper.

Answer (score 2):

In the Node Router - Stringify the response object. See below line.

```
 response.render("view", {responseObject:JSON.stringify(object)});
```

In HTML Script tag - user Template literals (Template strings) and use JSON.parse.

```
const json= `{{{responseObject}}}`;
const str = JSON.parse(json);
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: What if you dont want to use a script tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass templating syntax `{{ }}` inside a JSON object which is not valid.

You may need to do this instead:

`myView = new myView({ user : user });`

Answer (score 1):

To condense (what I found to be) the most helpful answers...

JSON helper for `handlebars` ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767928/accessing-handlebars-variable-via-javascript/30768079#30768079)):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("json", function (context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});
```

JSON helper for `express-handlebars` ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232574/need-handlebars-js-to-render-object-data-instead-of-object-object#comment55715219_10233247) and I updated to newest conventions):

```
app.engine(
    "handlebars",
    exphbs.engine({
        defaultLayout: "main",
        helpers: {
            json: function (context) { 
                return JSON.stringify(context);
            }
        }
    })
);
```

And then on the templating side: `{{json example}}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control over the output formatting you can write your own helper. This one has a recursive function to  traverse nested objects.

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('objToList', function(context) {
    function toList(obj, indent) {
      var res=""
      for (var k in obj) { 
          if (obj[k] instanceof Object) {
              res=res+k+"\n"+toList(obj[k], ("   " + indent)) ;
          }
          else{
              res=res+indent+k+" : "+obj[k]+"\n";
          }
      }
      return res;
    }    
    return toList(context,"");
  });
```

We used handlebars for email templates and this proved useful for a user like the following

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "First Name",
    "account": {
      "bank": "Wells Fargo",
      "sort code": " 123-456"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this:**

```
 <div>
   {{toJSON this}}   
</div>
```

**Define toJSON() in helper.js:**

```
var helper = {};
module.exports = helper;
    helper.toJSON = function (context) {
        return JSON.stringify(context);
    };
```

**In App.js:**

```
const helper = require('./helper/helper');
app.engine('hbs', handlebars({
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',
  extname: 'hbs',
  helpers: helper
}));
```