# How can I pass JSON to client using Node.js + HBS + Express?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Consider, I am sending JSON to client as follows in render page of [Express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) (using [hbs](https://github.com/donpark/hbs) as a view engine):

```
res.render('MyPage.html', { layout: false, PageTitle: 'Project Name', JSON_Data: {field1:'value',field2:'value2'}});
```

I am able to access and set title of html page by using `{{PageTitle}}`, following is the code.

```
  <title>{{PageTitle}}</title>
```

Now I want to show `JSON_data` into alert popup.

I've tried following way, but getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`, while debugging in chrome is shows `var jsonobj = [object Object]`

```
    function fbOnBodyLoad() {
        var jsonobj = {{JSON_data}};
        alert(jsonobj);
    }
```

Could any body give some idea on How to access `JSON_data` and show in alert

Advance Thanks

Comment: try `var jsonobj = "{{JSON_data}}";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always register a Handlebars helper to format the object into a string format (such as by using JSON.stringify), and then use that helper in your view. http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Answer (score 2):

to access the inner elements of the json object, try like this

```
var jsonobj = "{{JSON_data.field1}}";
```

may be this might solve the issue.

refer

[Handlebars.js parse object instead of [Object object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232574/handlebars-js-parse-object-instead-of-object-object)

Comment: No lucky with above code... :-(  getting `Error:'[Exception: ReferenceError: jsonobj is not defined]'`

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by doing in the server:

```
res.render('pages/register', {
                title: 'Register Form',
                messages: req.flash('error'),
                countries:JSON.stringify(countries)
        });
```

and then I used this countries variables to assign in angular controller like this:

```
angular.module('languagesApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

    $scope.algo = {{-countries}};
...
```