# How can i get D3 to read a Handlebars context object

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using Node + Express.js. One of my routes renders a Handlebars template and its context. The relevant part:

```
my_data = JSON.parse(body);
response.render( 'activity', my_data);
```

My question: Within that `activity.hbs` template, how to can I use D3 to create a plot from the `my_data` JSON object. In the relevant part of `activity.hbs` I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
          return JSON.stringify(context);
      });

     var datas = {{json my_data}}
     d3.select("body")
     .datum(datas)
     .enter()
    #do stuff with data
  </script>
```

I added the Helper after [reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232574/handlebars-js-parse-object-instead-of-object-object). When I try to render the view, it gives an Error:

`Missing helper: 'json' at Object.<anonymous>`

Is using a Helper the right way to approach this problem? How can I get D3 to read my context object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think is in your helper definition, basically you are defining the helper in the wrong place.
To define an helper, based on the documentation of [express3-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express3-handlebars) you have to register it in your express app code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    exphbs  = require('express3-handlebars'),

  app = express(),
  hbs;

  hbs = exphbs.create({
    // Specify helpers which are only registered on this instance.
    helpers: {
      // Your custom helper here
      json: function(context) { return JSON.stringify(context); }
    }
  });
  // Register it
  app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
  app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```