# Handlebars specific - escape both single and double quotes when passing Handlebars expression

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

HTML and Handlebars:

```
onclick='shareItem("{{name}}")'>
```

Does not successfully pass a safely escaped name when it has double quotes in it.

```
onclick="shareItem('{{name}}')">
```

Does not successfully pass a safely escaped name when it has single quotes in it.

I need to handle both eventualities- and even in the same string.

It feels sloppy to have to define a JS variable and pass it to a backslash adder.

Is there a cleaner way to do this with Handlebars or Moustache?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to register a [inline helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers) that manipulates the context. In your case, you need to escape a single or double quote.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('escape', function(variable) {
  return variable.replace(/(['"])/g, '\\$1');
});
```

By registering such helper, you can use it with a variable to achieve what you want.

```
{{ escape name }} # expects to escape any ' or "
```

I wrote a simple example to demonstrate this on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VLy4L/

Comment: Thanks for the response! The issue I see here, though, is that I'm adding the variable straight into the onClick event as an expression- and that's the point at which it breaks. The only way I saw around that was to drop the expression into javascript, which...feels sloppy.

Comment: @Kate Maybe you could use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to store data temporarily then access it within the javascript function?

Comment: Thanks, Seyeong! I went ahead and did it this way- passing in the entire object with the onClick event after setting the name as a data-* attribute.

Comment: @SeyeongJeong, please escape the escaping slash, too. Otherwise a backslash right before the quotes breaks the "escape" helper:
```javascript
Handlebars.registerHelper('escape', function(variable) {
  return variable.replace(/(['"\\])/g, '\\$1');
});
```

Answer (score 22):

I have a problem trying to escape single quotes, and I use the helper that handleblars provide, you can use triple brackets {{{ variable }}} for escape