# Pass object as parameter to onclick method in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
list: [
        { name: 'AAA',
          id: 1,
          age: 34
        },
        { name: 'BBB',
          id: 2,
          age: 24
        }
      ]
}
```

And a template like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each list}}
        <li onclick="someFunc({{this}})">{{name}} ({{age}}) </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Basically I just want to pass the current object , to a function that does something with it.

Now if I try it, then the generated HTML just has

```
 ... onclick="someFunc( [object Object] )" ...
```

whereas I'd like it to be like this:

```
 ... onclick="someFunc( {name: 'AAA', id: 1, age: 34} )" ...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Alt: I usually use data* attributes for the properties I want to render in such a scenario

Comment: How do you mean? Should I register my own helper method?

Comment: <li onclick="someFunc({{this}})" data-name="{{name}}">{{name}} ({{age}}) </li>

Comment: How would that solve my problem? I'm not getting the data properly inside someFunc(). Instead it looks like its doing a tosString on the object and sending me

Comment: It's not a direct answer, should have mentioned that, I render the values as data attributes and in the click handler for the li element I read the data attributes from the event source element and pass the values to any function that needs to be called (like someFun in your case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting for future references:

Got my answer from here:

[Handlebars.js parse object instead of [Object object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232574/handlebars-js-parse-object-instead-of-object-object)

Turns out Handlebar does a toString on the data before pasting into the template. All I had to do was to register a helper method that converts it back to json.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});

<li onclick="someFunc({{json this}})">{{name}} ({{age}}) </li>
```