# Accessing handlebars variable via javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm generating a handlebars view for express js framework, and I need to access the variables I pass to the view from inside a separate JavaScript file.

For example:

```
var foo = {{user.name}}
```

Someone got an idea? Helper?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The value of `user.name` needs to be output as a valid JavaScript expression if you want to include it in within a `<script>`, which will be reevaluating it as code.

Currently, if `user.name` is `"john.doe"` for example, the resulting script will be:

```
var foo = john.doe; // `john` is treated as an object with a `doe` property
```

---

The `user.name` at least needs to be in quotes so it's understood as a string value/literal.

```
var foo = "{{user.name}}";
```

```
// result
var foo = "john.doe";
```

You can also take advantage of JSON and JavaScript's similarities in syntax, outputting JSON that JavaScript can understand as an Expression, and will already include the quotes.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function (content) {
    return JSON.stringify(content);
});
```

```
var foo = {{{json user.name}}};
```

```
// result
var foo = "john.doe";
```

---

Note the triple `{{{...}}}` in the last example to disable HTML encoding, so you don't end up with:

```
var foo = &quot;john.doe&quot;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help ! I didn't saw anywhere this method : var foo = "{{user.name}}"; It's helped me a lot :)

Comment: I had `<script>var foo = {{{myJson}}}}</script>` where myJson was a pretty large object and seems like handlebars was unable to parse it. I could only get it working when I tried the solution I suggest in my answer

Comment: this one also works for me : var foo = "{{user.name}}"; thnx!

Comment: It is possible to get the value from a *.js file? Or i have to set the value to an element attribute `data-my-value` and get it this way?

Comment: Does this solution not work anymore? I've seen it elsewhere as well, but whenever I declare a variable assigned to {{{helper value}}} I get a syntax error with the first { as an unexpected token. How are people setting a variable equal to a value that has triple brackets in their client side javascript?

Answer (score 19):

Node can pass encoded JSON to the handlebars-view like this:

```
result.render('index', { 
  encodedJson : encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
});
```

The handlebars-view can decode and parse the json like so:

```
<script>
  var decodedJson = decodeURIComponent("{{{encodedJson}}}");
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(decodedJson);
</script>
```

---

Since anything passed to a handlebars-view will basically be injected straight into HTML, you should always pass encoded json and let the view decode it.

---

I tried the other suggestions in this thread. But they injected unencoded JSON into the handlebars view and that always gave me parsing errors. I have no idea how people got that to work, since it seems like Handlebars will parse variables as plain text.

I have not read up on how the Handlebars parser works - but it seems to me the only safe option is to use encoded JSON, like how I suggest in my examples.

Comment: encoding from the `render` function mangles my data into unusable `[object][object]` string. so i encode it via a view helper instead. additionally, using triple brackets `{{{` causes syntax error for me. double brackets works fine. all said, this solution manages to point me to the right direction.

Comment: This works for me but it only works if the script tag is directly in the .hbs file. If I link in a script file from another folder it doesn't pick up on the encoded text. Do you know if it is possible to access the encoded text in a foreign script file? Accessing it in a <script src="script/in/another/folder.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know how to do this in a separate js file either. These answers led me in the right direction, so thank you! I ended up JSON stringifying the data on the server-side, before I passed it to the page via render. However, I still couldn't get the code to work in a separate js file - which is fine. My use case was for Materialize input form autocomplete.

### node.js

```
// code is inside of a router.get block, therefore access to the response(res)

let customerData = {}
// add customer data with a loop, or whatever

const customers = JSON.stringify(customerData)

res.render('path/to/page', {
    customers
})
```

### client-side js

```
// code placed within script tags of the handlebars file, not a separate js file

const customers = {{{customers}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save as helper:

```
json: function (n: any) {
    return JSON.stringify(n)
},
```

Send:

```
<script src="/path/to/src" data="{{json data}}"></script>
```

Get:

```
const data= JSON.parse(document.body.querySelector('script[data]').getAttribute('data'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pageData = "{{pageData}}";
pageData = pageData.replace(/&quot;/g, `"`);
pageData = JSON.parse(pageData)
```

where pageData is an object (that may hold other objects)

Comment: Just add a third {} to the page data and it'll automatically not be escaped. No need for the second line.