# How to define an array within a <script> tag inside a hbs view template

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am learning full stack web development using Node/Express by building the voting app from [this](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-voting-app) FreeCodeCamp challenge. I am using Chart.js to show user votes on pie charts on the front end. The voting data needed for chart.js to display is provided by adding inline scripts in the Handlebars (hbs) view template.

Here is a snippet of the view:

```
<li class="list__item poll row" id="poll-{{this.id}}">
  <script>
    Pollstack.chartData.push({
      "id": "{{this.id}}",
      "type": "{{this.type}}",
      "datasets": {
        "options": {{this.options}} //PROBLEM HERE
      }
    });
  </script>

  <div class="poll__query col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <p class="poll__question">{{this.topic}}</p>
    <!-- some more markup here to display the options -->
 </div>
</li>
```

The options (JS line with the comment) is an array of objects that I retrieve from a MongoDB database. An example of that is here:

```
[
     {
     _id: 29302839023,
     optionText: "Karl Marx",
     votes: 12
    },
    {
     _id: 5454523231,
     optionText: "Virginia Woolf",
     votes: 14
    },
    {
     _id: 94895989348,
     optionText: "Thomas Hobbes",
     votes: 10
    }
]
```

I want to access this options array on the front end via external JavaScript script say: `app.js`. But this is what I get on the front end:

[image]

I have two questions about this and I will be very grateful to anyone who answers these:

1. How do I render an array rather that the [object Object], [object Object] string?
2. Are there any better ways (best practices) to pass the data to the front end JS rather than using inline scripts?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)' job is to replace mustache tags, `{{...}}`, with text. When you give Handlebars a complex object, like an array, it can only call that object's `.toString()` method and return the result. That is why you get `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` in your markup, this is the stringed version of your array.

You must remember that your template is producing text, not JavaScript. It won't be until the client loads and parses this text that it will be treated as JavaScript. This means that there is no concept of object references, only strings. Just as you explicitly wrote the `id`, `type`, and `datasets` properties into your template, you will need to explicitly write the text that will be parsed as the `options` array; using the Handlebars library to help you iterate and interpolate. The result would look like the following:

```
{
    "id": "{{id}}",
    "type": "{{type}}",
    "datasets": {
        "options": [
            {{#each options}}
                {
                    "id": {{_id}},
                    "optionText": "{{optionText}}",
                    "votes": {{votes}}
                }
                {{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
            {{/each}}
        ]
    }
}
```

If this seems a bit verbose, there is an alternative. What we are doing above is creating a string representation of our complex JavaScript object. This is the same objective as the `JSON.stringify()` method. We could, alternatively, `JSON.stringify` our data in the controller and render the result in our method invocation in the template. We would need to remember to use the triple mustaches so that our result will not be HTML escaped.

The view model in our controller would be updated to include the stringified JSON version of our Pollstack data:

```
pollstack_data: JSON.stringify({
    "id": id,
    "type": type,
    "datasets": {
        "options": options
    }
})
```

And then our view would need only to render this string without escaping the double-quotes:

```
Pollstack.chartData.push({{{pollstack_data}}});
```

Comment: I tried the approach you mentioned but I hadn't realized that I could do `{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}`. Thanks for enlightening me on that! Turns out the question is a dupe and he answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10233247/3714697) works best for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Encode the array into a urlencoded JSON string at controller side and decode the same at view side to get the array back.

### controller

```
var options = [
     {
     _id: 29302839023,
     optionText: "Karl Marx",
     votes: 12
    },
    {
     _id: 5454523231,
     optionText: "Virginia Woolf",
     votes: 14
    },
    {
     _id: 94895989348,
     optionText: "Thomas Hobbes",
     votes: 10
    }
]

options = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(options));
```

### view

```
<li class="list__item poll row" id="poll-{{this.id}}">
  <script>
    Pollstack.chartData.push({
      "id": "{{this.id}}",
      "type": "{{this.type}}",
      "datasets": {
        "options": JSON.parse(decodeURI("{{this.options}}"))
      }
    });
  </script>

  <div class="poll__query col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <p class="poll__question">{{this.topic}}</p>
    <!-- some more markup here to display the options -->
 </div>
</li>
```