# How do I pass a data object to my view with express-handlbars?

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I'm using `express-handlbars` as my template engine, and I can use it to place text into my script just fine:

`res.render('index', {foo: "something"});`

then in my template:
`var foo = "{{ foo }}"`

gives me `foo = "something"` in my client as I would expect. It works great for strings.

I can't figure out, however, how I can pass an entire object this way?

Comment: More info in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232574/handlebars-js-parse-object-instead-of-object-object

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it using a property like:

```
const data = { name: 'fooo' }
res.render('index', {foo: "something", data: data });
```

That way you will acess {{ data.name }}

Or you can pass the object directly

```
const data = { name: 'fooo' }
res.render('index', data);
```

and access using {{ name }}

To send the object to a javascript var into client you need to use the JSON.stringify(data)

var object = {{ JSON.stringify(data) }}

Comment: Oh, so I would send the stringify and parse in the client?

Comment: Actually if you only stringify it will work, because when the client loads it will be in the correct format. Remind to stringify directly on var, I mean without " like a string value